# Automated 10-K XBRL data grab using the SEC file structure

Tags: data, programming

I would like to write a program that takes as input a list of CIK/year/quarter entries.  The program should iterate through the list and, for each entry, grab XBRL financial data from the SEC website for the given CIK/year/quarter combination.

I can decipher some parts of the SEC file structure, but not all. For example, post fixing `Archives/edgar/data/1288776/11/` to the SEC base address gives a directory listing of all filings for the year 2011, for the company with CIK 1288776. Unfortunately I cannot make sense of the naming convention within this directory.

One way around this is to simply use the SEC's search tool. However, this requires that I use a web crawler and I would prefer to use ftp directly.

Can anyone clarify how accession numbers are assigned? How do others go about pulling financials from the SEC website?

Answer (score 7):

Look in

```
edgar/full-index/{YYYY}/QTR{N}/xbrl.idx
```

You can grab the compressed version too:

```
xbrl.{Z,sit,gz,zip}
```

This will state what file you want.

---

For example, I want AOL's 10-K that was filed in the first quarter of 2012. So I download

```
edgar/full-index/2012/QTR1/xbrl.gz
```

After decompressing, I see that AOL's 10-K is available at

```
edgar/data/1468516/0001193125-12-076633.txt
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more on this useful info?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this XBRL-Crawler:
https://github.com/eliangcs/pystock-crawler
It runs on Python but might be outdated.

You also can download the Text-Files using this Crawler: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SECEdgar

I will test the first one, but the second one works fine.

Answer (score 0):

sec-api (https://www.npmjs.com/package/sec-api) provides a websocket-based real-time API using Socket.IO - works with server-side (eg Node.js) and client-side (eg React, React Native, Angular, Vue) JavaScript.

The API returns new filings in JSON format, eg:

```
{  
  companyName: 'WALT DISNEY CO/ (0001001039) (Issuer)',  
  type: '4',  
  description: 'FORM 4',  
  linkToFilingDetails:    'https://www.sec.gov/...',  
  linkToHtmlAnnouncement:    'https://www.sec.gov/...',  
  announcedAt: '2018-12-21T20:02:07-05:00'
}
```

You can hook-up to the websocket channel, and ignore all filings where type doesn't equal '10-K'.

However, the API doesn't return historical filings.

The Node.js implementation seems to be very simple:

```
const api = require('sec-api')(); 
api.on('filing', filing => console.log(filing));
```